# Parsing XML file with lxml in Python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

I need to parse an xml file, lest say called example.xml, that looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<nf:rpc-reply xmlns:nf="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" xmlns="http://www.cisco.com/nxos:1.0:if_manager">
 <nf:data>
  <show>
   <interface>
    <__XML__OPT_Cmd_show_interface___readonly__>
     <__readonly__>
      <TABLE_interface>
       <ROW_interface>
        <interface>Ethernet1/1</interface>
        <state>down</state>
        <state_rsn_desc>Link not connected</state_rsn_desc>
        <admin_state>up</admin_state>
```

I need to get "interface", and "state" elements as such: ['Ethernet1/1', 'down']
Here is my solution that doesnt work:

```
from lxml import etree

parser = etree.XMLParser()
tree = etree.parse('example.xml', parser)

print tree.xpath('//*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/interface/text()')
print tree.xpath('//*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/state/text()')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to handle namespaces here:

```
from lxml import etree

parser = etree.XMLParser()
tree = etree.parse('example.xml', parser)
ns = {'ns': 'http://www.cisco.com/nxos:1.0:if_manager'}

interface = tree.find('//ns:ROW_interface', namespaces=ns)
print [interface.find('.//ns:interface', namespaces=ns).text,
       interface.find('.//ns:state', namespaces=ns).text]
```

Prints:

```
['Ethernet1/1', 'down']
```

---

Using [`collections.namedtuple()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
interface_node = tree.find('//ns:ROW_interface', ns)

Interface = namedtuple('Interface', ['interface', 'state'])
interface = Interface(interface=interface_node.find('.//ns:interface', ns).text,
                      state=interface_node.find('.//ns:state', ns).text)

print interface
```

Prints:

```
Interface(interface='Ethernet1/1', state='down')
```

Comment: that works, is it possible to add the extracted data directly to a named tuple instead of a list? like so interafces = ('interfaces'['interface', 'state'])

Comment: @dragon great, you can also try to make use of [`lxml.objectify`](http://lxml.de/objectify.html)..

Comment: one last bit, can we also parse a string in the same way rather than a file?

Comment: @dragon sure, use `fromstring` instead of `parse`.